# Mysql query for hotel room availability

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create an online room reservation system for a small hotel. One of the tables of the database 
is supposed to hold the bookings. It has an autonumber field, customer data fields, two date fields for arrival and departure, and a number field for the number of rooms booked.
A search page submits the arrival and departure dates to a result page which is then supposed to tell the customer how many rooms are available within the period if any. This is where it all goes wrong.
 I just can't get an accurate count of the number of rooms already booked within the period requested.

```
guest  | arrive     | depart       |booked
Smith  | 2002-06-11 | 2002-06-18   | 1
Jones  | 2002-06-12 | 2002-06-14   | 2
Brown  | 2002-06-13 | 2002-06-16   | 1
White  | 2002-06-15 | 2002-06-17   | 2
```

If the hotel has 9 rooms, here is a day-by-day listing of the number of available rooms.
I want the result like this.

```
 date        available     status
2002-06-10  |   9      |  Hotel is empty
2002-06-11  |   8      |  Smith checks in
2002-06-12  |   6      |  Jones checks in
2002-06-13  |   5      |  Brown checks in
2002-06-14  |   7      |  Jones checks out
2002-06-15  |   5      |  White checks in
2002-06-16  |   6      |  Brown checks out
2002-06-17  |   8      | White checks out
2002-06-18  |   9      | Smith checks out
```

Please help me to find a solution

Comment: Please post the query that you are currently using which does not produce 100% perfect results and maybe we can help you improve it.

Comment: To the extent that this is a display issue, consider handling those aspects of the problem in application code.

Comment: Also, (why) must a guest book all rooms for the same number of days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A calendar table isn't strictly necessary for problems of this nature, but they can help to conceptualise the problem in a quick and easy manner. So I have a calendar table holding dates from 1900 until 4000 and something...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(booking_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,guest VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
,arrive DATE NOT NULL
,depart DATE NOT NULL
,booked INT NOT NULL
,UNIQUE KEY(guest,arrive)
);

INSERT INTO my_table (guest,arrive,depart,booked) VALUES
('Smith','2002-06-11','2002-06-18',1),
('Jones','2002-06-12','2002-06-14',2),
('Brown','2002-06-13','2002-06-16',1),
('White','2002-06-15','2002-06-17',2);

SELECT x.dt
     , 9 - COALESCE(SUM(booked),0) available 
  FROM calendar x 
  LEFT 
  JOIN my_table y 
    ON x.dt >= y.arrive AND x.dt < y.depart 
 WHERE x.dt BETWEEN '2002-06-10' AND '2002-06-20' 
 GROUP 
    BY dt;
+------------+-----------+
| dt         | available |
+------------+-----------+
| 2002-06-10 |         9 |
| 2002-06-11 |         8 |
| 2002-06-12 |         6 |
| 2002-06-13 |         5 |
| 2002-06-14 |         7 |
| 2002-06-15 |         5 |
| 2002-06-16 |         6 |
| 2002-06-17 |         8 |
| 2002-06-18 |         9 |
| 2002-06-19 |         9 |
| 2002-06-20 |         9 |
+------------+-----------+
11 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```